# Generate request in SOAPUI with arrayofstring type

Tags: soap

I am trying to generate the SOAP Request inside SOAP UI Tool. The SOAP Request look like

```
 <soapenv:Body><pur:purge soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <name xsi:type="xsd:string">?</name>
     <pwd xsi:type="xsd:string">?</pwd>
     <network xsi:type="xsd:string">?</network>
     <opt xsi:type="pur:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
     <uri xsi:type="pur:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[]"/>
  </pur:purgeRequest>
```

I am not able to understand how to pass values for opt and uri?.

I tried giving array of uri as

```
<uri>
<url>url 1</url>
<url>url 2</url>
</uri>
```

Which is wrong !.

I am also trying to search about ArrayOfString type but couldn't get a good explanation about it's usage.

Can some one help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OMG, haven't seen that in a while. What you got there is a SOAP array with `ArrayOfString` being a subtype of `soapenc:Array` I guess.

The best source of information you can find is the [SOAP specification itself, section 5.4.2.Arrays](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383522).

But do note that the SOAP array is a strange beast and because it was improperly understood, it generated some problems. For that fact, the [WS-I Basic Profile discourages its use](http://www.ws-i.org/Profiles/BasicProfile-1.1.html#soapenc_Array), since there are better ways of declaring arrays (using elements with `maxOccurs="unbounded"`).

If you have control over the web service, I would suggest to change that to an unbounded list of elements.

Comment: thanks dpb , I changed xsd:string[] to xsd:string[1] and it worked ! I will go through the link related to Array

Comment: I'm trying to do exactly what is suggested in this answer - get rid of SOAP-ENC:Arrays in the project my company is working on.
Could anybody provide some info on which exactly problems are related to using such arrays vs using lists? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

The following code will work for you,

```
<soapenv:Body><pur:purge soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
     <name xsi:type="xsd:string">?</name>
     <pwd xsi:type="xsd:string">?</pwd>
     <network xsi:type="xsd:string">?</network>
     <opt xsi:type="pur:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[2]">
        <item>Enter the value here..</item>
        <item>Enter the value here..</item>
     </opt>
     <uri xsi:type="pur:ArrayOfString" soapenc:arrayType="xsd:string[1]">
         <item>Enter the value here..</item>
     </uri>
  </pur:purgeRequest>
```

Comment: Oh, and there are a lot of "not an answer" flags on here because the XML wasn't formatted properly. It just looked like "? ? ? Enter the value here.. Enter the value here.. Enter the value here.." Please read the formatting help.